# React Native I want to Scroll two Flatlist in single Scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hello All i m working on horizontal listing and i have two horizontal flatlist in my screens ! so what i want is if i scroll first flatlist... it reflects on my second flatlist is this possible in our react native if possible then give me such suggestions[image: you can see my first list if i scroll i want to both]

here is my flatlist code

```
   <FlatList
    data={categories}
    horizontal
    scrollEnabled={true}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
      return (
        <Box mr={index === categories.length - 1 ? 0 : "10px"}>
          <CategoryTile category={item} inlineTitle={false} inGrid={true} />
        </Box>
      );
    }}
  />
```

Comment: I can give you one suggestion to implement so, Add a reference(useRef) to your second flatlist. And then make use of onScroll prop on your first flatlist. In this onScroll function you will get the position of your first flatlist scrolling. Then here in this method using the second flatlist reference you can scroll the second flatlist using the scroll data received. 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltooffset

Comment: Hey Nice Suggestion i implemtated as u said i got d exact value and puted in useRef and using that my second flatlist..! but noting is working

Comment: const handleScroll = (event : any) => {
    count.current = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
 }.   /// 1 St Flat list       <FlatList
        onScroll={handleScroll}.   ///2nd Flast List       <FlatList
        ref={count}
        data={categories}

Comment: my second Flatlist nothing is scroll while i set ref inside 2nd flatlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function GroundScreen() {
  const refFlatList1 = useRef(null);
  const refFlatList2 = useRef(null);
  const [arr1, setArr1] = useState(Arr1);
  const [arr2, setArr2] = useState(Arr2);
  const [scrollingRightSideAmount, setScrollingRightSideAmount] = useState(0);

  function renderItemArr1({item, index}) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 300,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'black',
        }}></View>
    );
  }
  function renderItemArr2({item, index}) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 300,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'black',
        }}></View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>FlatList 1</Text>
        <FlatList
          ref={refFlatList1}
          data={arr1}
          renderItem={renderItemArr1}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => String(index)}
          horizontal
          onScroll={e => {
            if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x > 0 && scrollingRightSideAmount > e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x) {
              setScrollingRightSideAmount(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
              refFlatList2.current.scrollToOffset({offset:e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,animated:true});
            } else {
              setScrollingRightSideAmount(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
              refFlatList2.current.scrollToOffset({offset:e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,animated:true});
            }
          }}
        />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>FlatList 2</Text>
        <FlatList
          ref={refFlatList2}
          data={arr2}
          renderItem={renderItemArr2}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => String(index)}
          horizontal
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const Arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Hope this helps !!! :)

Comment: This solution is excellent. If this could have optimized the delay between two scrolls then it'd have been better.

Comment: You can try animated lib for smooth Flatlist/Scrollview animation.